# From modelpopup table responsive scroll accessible in Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I'm opening a model from a button which is inside a responsive table.
If my content of a popup is more then I am able to see in `table-responsive`, the horizontal scroll from modal popup appears and I'm able to access it from modal popup.

Please help me not to show this horizontal scroll in modal popup.

Thanks in advance.

My code is :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
   <div class="table-responsive">
   <table class="table ">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>#</td>
          <td>First Name</td>
          <td>Last Name</td>
          <td>Username</td>
          <td>details</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><select class="form-control"><option>NON duplicate</option><option>duplicate</option></select></td>
          <td><input class="form-control" type="text"/></td>
             <td><input class="form-control" type="text"/></td>
             <td><input class="form-control" type="text"/></td>
             <td><input type="button" value="search" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><select class="form-control" ><option>ABC</option><option>XYZ</option></select></td>
          <td><input class="form-control" type="text"/></td>
             <td><input class="form-control" type="text"/></td>
             <td><input class="form-control" type="text"/></td>
             <td><input class="form-control" type="text"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><select><option>ABC</option><option>XYZ</option></select></td>
          <td><input class="form-control" type="text"/></td>
             <td><input class="form-control" type="text"/></td>
             <td><input class="form-control" type="text"/></td>   <td>
             <input class="form-control" type="text"/></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
   </div>
        </div>
    </div>


</div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
       test<br/>
       test<br/>
       test<br/>
       test<br/>
       test<br/>
       test<br/>
       test<br/>
       test<br/>
       test<br/>
       test<br/>
       test<br/>       
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is behaving normally. Are you using 3.2?

Comment: yes 3.2. hi i am using mozilla and resolution is 320*480